# Terraform, digitalocean. Как добавить существующий ssh ключ?

Tags: ssh, digitalocean, terraform

Как при создании **droplet** добавить **ssh ключ** который уже добавлен в **VPC**?
Пытался добавить его через переменную, но получил ошибку:

```
SSH Key is already in use on your account.
```

Понял, что его нужно забрать через **data sourse** и даже нашел два метода `digitalocean_ssh_key` и `digitalocean_ssh_keys`, но первый требует точное имя ключа, которого я не знаю, второй должен выгрузить список всех ключей, но я не понимаю куда и как этим дальше пользоваться, не нашел буквально ни одного примера.

Comment: [Тут пример как получить список ключей с атрибутами](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#tag/SSH-Keys)